# WeChat Sharing Music - Get rid of background pixelated edges

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, sharing, wechat

I have implemented Sharing music features on WeChat.

Sharing on **iOS** works good. But when sharing on **Android**, the edge of the background are white and pixelated. I'm thinking is it caused by the low pixel of images? I’m looking for a solutions to get rid of those pixelated edges.

**Code for Android:**

```
WXMusicObject musicObj = new WXMusicObject();
musicObj.MusicUrl = link;              // URL to open when the song is clicked
musicObj.MusicDataUrl = userAudioURL;  // URL of actual music data

WXMediaMessage msg = new WXMediaMessage();
msg.mediaObject = musicObj; 

int imgId = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField("icon").GetValue(null);
Bitmap thumbBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Forms.Context.Resources, imgId);
Bitmap thBitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(thumbBitmap, 150, 150, true);
thumbBitmap.Recycle();
using (System.IO.MemoryStream outStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
   thBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 150, outStream);
   msg.ThumbData = outStream.ToArray();
}

SendMessageToWX.Req req = new SendMessageToWX.Req();
req.Transaction = buildTransaction("music");
req.Message = msg;
req.Scene = SendMessageToWX.Req.WXSceneSession;  //chat 
mWxApi.SendReq(req);
```

Comment: What does the original source image/drawable look like? What is the original resolution?

Comment: @SushiHangover It looks to me like the background image is a stretched & blurred version of the Icon. So my guess to solve this issue would be to not have rounded edges in the original icon, and just use a square with right-corner edges. The reason it looks OK on iOS is because there is no transparency; the corners of the icon are white, and if you look closely, you can see the background image's top left & right corners are also slightly lighter due to the white being blurred with the rest of the image. Wechat (on Android at least) uses square avatars anyways, so thats what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out the root cause. For sharing music on WeChat, background will set to thumbnail images.

I solved this with using a higher pixel images, so background image wouldn't stretched and can displayed without pixelation.